# How to chop a complex number?

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I'm solving some differential equations by iterating and I want to use Chop to get rid of noice smaller than a certain threshold. However, I found that Chop only "chops" the real part, not the imaginary part. My question is, which function can I use in order to approximate both real and imaginary parts that are very close to zero by zero?

For example, if I try to do

```
A = 10^(-50);
B = I*10^(-50);
Chop[A + B]
```

The result is just that same number (and actually not even the real number is getting chopped so I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly). I would want the result to be zero.

Comment: `I found that Chop only "chops" the real part` are you sure about this? can you show a MWE showing this? Because I tried this `a = 3;
b = I*  3.000000000001;
r = a + b;
Chop[r]` and it gives `3. + 3. I` so it seems to work. This is using V12

Comment: `Threshold` does this, but only on arrays: `Threshold[{A + B}]`.

Answer (score 8):

> I would want the result to be zero.

Exact numbers do not get `Choped`, because they are exact

```
A = 10^(-50);
B = I*10^(-50);
Chop[A + B]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get chop to work, The numbers need to be real and not exact as you have it. So just add a `.`

```
A = 10.^(-50);
B = I*10.^(-50);
Chop[A + B]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or apply `N` on it

```
Chop[N[A + B]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]